# How to generalize a system characteristic equation to nth order

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have the characteristic equation of the system as 
   $|sI-A_e-L_oC_e|=0$

Here, $I$ is the identity matrix of order $(n+1), A_e, L_o$ and $C_e$ are the matrices defined as shown in the attached figure.

I want to substitute the matrices (shown in the figure) into the equation and develop a generalized characteristic equation of order $n+1$. While I have been able to develop characteristic equation of order $3 (n=2)$, but it is almost impossible to extend it to $(n+1)$ order. Can anyone please tell me some technique that can generalize the above characteristic equation easily?
[image]

[image]

[image]